# Streaming data in node.js with ws and websocket-stream

Tags: node.js, stream, websocket

I'm trying to stream data from a server to a client using websockets -- in particular, ws and websocket stream.  However, the stream seems to be closing too early, and I only receive two chunks worth of data.  Here is the simple example.

I have a server:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var websocketStream = require('websocket-stream');

var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8098});
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');

wss.on('connection', function connect(ws) {
  var stream = websocketStream(ws);
  var rs = fs.createReadStream('foo.big');
  rs.pipe(stream);
});
```

and a client that connects and streams foo.big to a local file using pipe():

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var websocket = require('websocket-stream');

var rs = fs.createWriteStream('big.out');

rs.on('open', function () {
  var ws = websocket('http://localhost:8098');

  ws.on('open', function () {
    ws.pipe(rs);
  }).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }).on('close', function (err) {
    console.log("Closing");
  });
});
```

Any ideas why I would only be getting a few packets of data? If I remove the call in the client to pipe, and just receive the data in chunks, it seems to receive all the data.

Comment: Interestingly, if I pass {end: false} to the pipe() call in the server, the client receives all the data. This is confusing -- why would the filesystem be ending early?

Answer (score 4):

There is a couple of things wrong with the above (as of 2017).

1. You would rather want to listen for the `fs.readStream()` `close` event
2. You should not be listening to the `websocket-stream` `open` event, as you can assume it to be open

Also, performance: `ws` is likely not suited for server to server communication. Consider alternatives, like `net`, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862250/sending-a-file-to-node-js-through-tcp), or various other lower than `ws` level ways.

Find a full example [here on my GH](https://github.com/eljefedelrodeodeljefe/knowledge/tree/master/bounties/ws_stream_ends_to_early).

```
const fs = require('fs')
const websocket = require('websocket-stream')

const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('big.out')

writeStream.on('open', () => {
  let ws = websocket('http://localhost:8098')

  ws.pipe(writeStream)

  ws.on('error', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
  }).on('close', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`Closing ws with: ${fs.statSync('big.out').size} bytes`)
  })

  writeStream.on('close', () => {
    console.log(`Closing file stream with: ${fs.statSync('big.out').size} bytes`)
  })
})
```